# Modify Agent Jobs script to limit results for last x days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a relatively new DBA (less than a year) and my T-SQL skills still need some (okay...a lot of) work.

I am using a registered server to monitor my MS SQL 2005, 2008, and 2012 environment.  I use the following script daily to monitor my agent jobs.  This script is pretty good for what I need.  However, it's returning job info/status going back years.  I'd like to return status for last x days only; but my attempts to modify this script have been unsuccessful.

Here is the script:

```html
SELECT
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    , [sJSTP].[step_uid] AS [StepID]
    , [sJSTP].[step_id] AS [StepNo]
    , [sJSTP].[step_name] AS [StepName]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[last_run_outcome]
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Unknown'
      END AS [LastRunStatus]
    , STUFF(
            STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJSTP].[last_run_duration] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                , 3, 0, ':')
            , 6, 0, ':')
      AS [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)]
    , [sJSTP].[last_run_retries] AS [LastRunRetryAttempts]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[last_run_date]
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE 
            CAST(
                CAST([sJSTP].[last_run_date] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJSTP].[last_run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                        , 3, 0, ':')
                    , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
      END AS [LastRunDateTime]
FROM
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sJSTP]
    INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
        ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [sJOB].[job_id]
WHERE [sJSTP].[last_run_outcome] <>1 
 --AND DATEDIFF(day,[sJSTP].[last_run_date],getdate()) < 31
 --AND [sJSTP].[last_run_date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY [JobName], [StepNo]​
```

I included two of my more recent attempt to modify the script as described.  Predictably, they both erred out with the following:

```html
: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime​
```

My guess is there is a problem with data type (numeric vs datetime).   I'd appreciate some assistance with modifying this script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Field "last_run_date" is stored as an 8-digit INT, which SQL Server won't implicitly cast to a date.  It will implicitly cast a CHAR(8) to a date.  So just do

```
CAST(last_run_date AS CHAR(8)) > ...
```

Compare these examples:

-- this one fails

```
select case when 20150527 >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) then 1 else 0 end
```

-- this one succeeds

```
select case when cast(20150527 as CHAR(8)) >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) then 1 else 0 end
```

So just correct your WHERE clause to include the CAST:

```
WHERE [sJSTP].[last_run_outcome] <>1 
    AND cast([sJSTP].[last_run_date] as CHAR(8)) >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have been trying to understand your suggestion within the context of the script, but something is eluding me.  I am unsure how to incorporate your suggestion into the script.  It appears the script already uses CAST([sJSTP].[last_run_date] AS CHAR(8))--albeit as part of a larger statement combining both last_run_date and last_run_time.

Comment: Yes, the script already uses the CAST in the SELECT statement.  You need to do that in the WHERE clause as well.  That is where the conversion error is happening.  I will edit the post to show exactly how to use the suggestion.